# Formidable Forms - Likert Scale pre-populated

Tags: wordpress, forms, formidable

I am trying to build a survey as the 2nd stage of a Form journey. Stage 1 is Form 1 where visitors can select 'Lenders' - during stage 2 I want to provide survey questions with multiple possible options for each 'Lender' selected in Stage 1 (Form 1)

My initial thoughts for solutions are:

- A likert scale, where the rows are pre-populated with 'Lenders' selected in Form 1
- A Dropdown question where the field label changes based on 'Lenders' selected in Form 1

Any help is greatly appreciated as my brain is melting

[Example Likert Scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stbiv.png)

I have tried using the (ID) from the 'Lender' field to populate the scale - this just shows the (ID) and doesn't update with the options selected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.